# How to make this code become more effcient?

Tags: java

So I have been doing competitive programming using java, my code is ACCEPTED in codeforces. But I still think this code doesn't look so good, cause it needs 2 "for loops" to identify the duplication. if it is only one "for loops", it still has duplication in the strings.

This is the problem: https://codeforces.com/problemset/problem/236/A.

So basically, the code will try to find the distinct characters in the strings, then if the length of the string is odd, it will print "IGNORE HIM", else "CHAT WITH HER!".

```
import java.util.Scanner;
    
    public class Main {
    
        public static void main(String[] args) {
        String a;
    
        int counter=0;
        Scanner sc= new Scanner(System.in);
        a=sc.next();
        StringBuilder b= new StringBuilder(a);
        int count = 0;
    
        for(int i=0;i<b.length();i++)
        {
            for(int j=i+1;j<b.length();j++) {
                if(b.charAt(i)==b.charAt(j)) {
                    b=b.deleteCharAt(j);
                }
    
            }
        }
            for(int i=0;i<b.length();i++)
            {
                for(int j=i+1;j<b.length();j++) {
                    if(b.charAt(i)==b.charAt(j)) {
                        b=b.deleteCharAt(j);
                    }
    
                }
            }
    
        counter=b.length();
        if(counter%2==0)
        {
            System.out.println("CHAT WITH HER!");
    
        }
        else
        {
            System.out.println("IGNORE HIM!");
        }
        }
    }
```

Comment: You can use hashmap in O(n)

Comment: Other option could be to use Set

Comment: Questions about Optimize working code is better asked at [codereview.SE]

Comment: Poor title. Rewrite to summarize your specific technical issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can replace most of this code by this one line:

```
int count = a.chars().distinct().count();
```

This transforms you string input into a stream of characters, gets the distinct values and returns the count.

Comment: Technically its integer representation of chars.

Answer (score 1):

Using streams is a good option. If you want to go plain old route, then you can use a hashset. Basically if character is in hashset, then move to next char, else add to hashset and increase counter by 1.

Answer (score 1):

Building upon and completing @Guillaume's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62900946/how-to-make-this-code-become-more-effcient/62901159#62901159)

```java
String a = "xiaodao";
String out = a.chars().distinct().count() % 2 == 0 ? "CHAT WITH HER!" : "IGNORE HIM!";
System.out.println(out);
```

Answer (score 1):

I would use a Hashset because it will contain a distinct set of all characters you add.  You can just go through the list once and use size() to get the unique character count.

```
...
Set<Character> characters = new HashSet<>()
for(int i=0;i<b.length();i++)
{
     characters.add(b.charAt(i));
}
if(characters.size()%2==0) {
...
```